The fluxoid quantization
In Barone's Physical Applications of the Josephson Effect chapter 12 section 1 it says : The density of pairs at a given point r (in the
superconductor) is given by
$$
\psi^*(r)\psi(r) = \rho(r)
$$
Therefore, in order to have physical meaning, the function $\psi (r)$ must be single valued. This implies that on a closed loop in the superconductor the phase $\varphi$ can change only by a quantity $2\pi n$, where $n$ is an integer.
Why does that imply that the phase can change only by a quantity $2\pi n$ ?
